# No debugger via text IDE (Go32v2)

Tags: ide, pascal, freepascal

I just installed Free Pascal v3.2.2 (within dosbox-x). Unfortunately debugging from the (go32v2) IDE doesn't work. Whatever I do, it says "no debugger support available".

Update: It seems that the build was compiled without debugger support!

Comment: UPDATE: The IDE from version 3.2.0 seems to work. I suspect the build was compiled without debug functionality. But why hasn't anyone noticed this yet?